# Dandelion Datatables + Thymleaf + dt:format

Tags: datatable, thymeleaf, dandelion

I've tried to implement the formatting attribute for Dandelion Datatables [as specified here](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/docs/ref/thymeleaf/th.html) using Thymeleaf to no avail, like so:

```
<table dt:table="true" dt:serverside="true" dt:url="@{/somefnplace}">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th dt:property="someCurrencyField" dt:format="{0, number, #.##}">
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

...but this does not do anything. Anyone got an idea on how this is supposed to work, or do I have to create render functions for every column because this feature is broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `dt:format` attribute is not compatible with AJAX sources. See the last column of the link you've mentioned.

In the upcoming version, it will simply be removed, because using DOM sources, [expression utility objects](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#appendix-b-expression-utility-objects) meet all needs perfectly.

So yes, currently the only way is to use the `dt:renderFunction` attribute, which will refer to a rendering function, one for each column to need to display in a specific format.